# Prove that $\kappa (A) = \sup\Big\{ \frac{||Ax||}{||Ay||},\ ||x|| = ||y||\Big\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-norms, condition-number

I am trying to prove this for my numerical analysis class. This is from chapter 4.4 of Kincaid and Cheney's book. So far I haven´t got any good idea.

I have tried
$$
\|A\| \|A^{-1}\| = \sup \|A\frac{u}{\|v\|}\|\cdot \|A^{-1}\frac{v}{\|u\|}\|,\quad \|u\|=\|v\|
$$

But I coudn't advance any further. What confuses me the most is that there is not $||A^{-1}||$ in the equation. As far as I know there is not relation between a matrix norm and its inverse norm besides $\|A^{-1}\| \geq (\|A\|)^{-1}$ which haven't been useful. Please help.

Comment: Can you clarify what are $A$, $x$, and $y$? Also which norm is it? It's not clear from the context.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, $\|A^{-1}\| = \sup_{z \neq 0} { \|A^{-1} z \| \over \|z\|} = \sup_{y \neq 0} { \| y \| \over \|Ay\|} = \sup_{\|y\| = 1} { 1 \over \|Ay\|}$.

Comment: $A$ is any invertible square matrix, $x$ and $y$ are vectors so this is related with the subordinate norm of $A$

Comment: @copper.hat It is not clear to me why the second equality is true. Why $\frac{||A^{-1}z||}{||z||} = \frac{||y||}{||Ay||}$

Comment: @jushou1302 Substitute $Ay=z$.

Answer (score 4):

For any $x,y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|$ we have, with $z=Ay$,
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|Ay\|}=\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\,\frac{\|y\|}{\|Ay\|}
=\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\,\frac{\|A^{-1}z\|}{\|z\|}\leq\|A\|\,\|A^{-1}\|. 
$$
Now fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exist $x,z$ such that $$\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}>\|A\|-\varepsilon\,\qquad\qquad\frac{\|A^{-1}z\|}{\|z\|}>\|A^{-1}\|-\varepsilon.
$$
By rescaling $z$ if needed, we may assume that $\|A^{-1}z\|=\|x\|$. With $y=A^{-1}z$,
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|Ay\|}=\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}\,\frac{\|A^{-1}z\|}{\|z\|}
>(\|A\|-\varepsilon)(\|A^{-1}\|-\varepsilon). 
$$
As $\|x\|=\|y\|$ and this can be done for each $\varepsilon>0$, this shows that
$$
\|A\|\,\|A^{-1}\|=\sup\Big\{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|Ay\|}:\ \|x\|=\|y\|\Big\}.
$$

Comment: Does the first equality hold for any $x$ and $y$? It looks that you need $||x|| = ||y|$

Comment: Indeed. Edited.

Comment: Thank you. I could understand it and completed my homework